# why "systemctl" not working in Ubuntu terminal on Windows?

Tags: windows-subsystem-for-linux, systemctl, start-stop-daemon

I need to reload the daemon using systemctl command in ubuntu terminal on window 10. I attached the error I received.

The error:

```
bashdos@yana:~$ systemctl
System has not been booted with systemd as init system (PID 1). Can't operate.
```

Comment: What about `service`?

Comment: @Geno Chen I can't understand your question? Could you please explain ir

Comment: I am not sure if `service` can be used, for example `service start sshd`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

WSL doesn't have systemd implemented therefore in Ubuntu you need to run for example `service start ssh` or you can call the binary directly such as `/etc/init.d/ssh start/stop/restart`.

Answer (score 1):

I had this problem running WSL 2

the solution was the command

```
 $ sudo dockerd
```

Open other terminal and try it

```
 $ docker ps -a
```

if after that you still have a problem with permission, run the command:

```
 $ sudo usermod -aG docker your-user
```